# Sprite2D texture repeat switches from Mirror to Disabled when resizing window

Tags: textures, godot, gdscript, godot-4, bug

In Godot 4, I set the texture repeat of a Sprite2D to 'Mirror',

When I run the game, it works fine except when I resize the window — then the texture repeat switches to 'disabled'.

Is there a workaround?

I found a github issue about it that says it's fixed in Godot 4.2, but that isn't released yet.

Comment: Sounds like you could handle the resize signal of the Window and set the texture repeat to what you want in the handler method.